# C# WPF - Not all images show up on grid

Tags: c#, wpf, random, bitmap, grid

I can't load all grid spots with images at once. I have a 5x5 grid and it is intended to load 25 random images in random spots. With 25 images it should fill out the entire grid.

I can't figure out why there are empty spots when I load 25 or when I load less. I'm having one image repeat itself throughout the entire grid in order to avoid image format related issues. I think the problem might be related to the `Random` class.

Here is the code:

```
private readonly Random _r = new Random();

public void LoadPictures(int numberOfPictures)
{
    // Create a 2d array of specified dimensions
    var picArr = new bool[5, 5]; 

    for (int j = 0; j < numberOfPictures; j++) 
    {
        // Get the images from the specified folder
        string[] imagePaths = Directory.GetFiles(
            Environment.CurrentDirectory + "/images");

        bool invalidPlacement = true; // default is true

        while (invalidPlacement)
        {
            var i = new Image();  

            try
            {
                // Load the image with a random Picture
                var uri = new Uri(imagePaths[_r.Next(0, imagePaths.Length)]);
                i.Source = new BitmapImage(uri);
                Debug.WriteLine(uri.AbsolutePath);
                i.Width = ImageWidth;
                i.Height = ImageHeight;                    
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            // Put it somewhere
            int row = _r.Next(5);
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50));
            int col = _r.Next(5);

            // Check to see if there is something there
            if (picArr[col, row] == false)
            {
                picArr[col, row] = true;
                Grid.SetColumn(i, col);
                Grid.SetRow(i, row);
                Background2.Children.Add(i);
                AnimateControl(i, 100, 100, 0, 0);
                invalidPlacement = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What behavior are you seeing exactly? It's not clear in your question.

Comment: Also, why the sleep between the calls to Next?

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles()` gets all the files in a dir, even hidden. You're sure the directory contains _only_ images?  You might be picking up thumbs.db or something.

Comment: Just add some breakpoints and debug your code to find out what is actually happening.

Comment: thanks for all suggestions. It helps me try things that I didn't tjink of,